# Swipes generating on click on popup controls Firemonkey Delphi

Tags: android, user-interface, delphi, firemonkey

I am new to firemonkey and mobile apps. I have a tabbed android application which I am using the swipe left and swipe right gesture to transition between tab pages ala most android apps.
One of my tab pages is filled with popup boxes. It is impossible to swipe out of this page without triggering the popup list even though the application is now on another tab page.
I can disable gestures and use a button based tab control, but this is not android like.

I have tried a number of things:

I can intercept the `OnClick` event and enable and disable the popup, but I am unable at that time to detect that the click was part of a swipe gesture. It has not yet switched tabs, using doidle or other processmessages type approaches does not let it finish switching tabs, and I do not know how to peek at events in the que to see that a swipe gesture is pending.

I disabled the `OnClick` event and used a long tap from the gesture manager assigned to the popup to activate the popup.  The problem is that if I do that then the swipe gestures no longer work, and never generate an event. I tried this same approach filling a panel with the popupboxes and assigning the gesture manager to the panel and again, the swipe actions seem to never be triggered.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a master gesture swipe left / swipe right, you can add a transparent layout (with BringToFront) on the foreground of your TabControl and use catch swipe on it.

Comment: I can use some more details.  I started with the multi-tab example. There the gesture manager is on the main form and the tabcontrol is also on the main form.  The gesture manager collects the gestures on all the tabs successfully. The problem is that a 'swipe' also generates a click event on the underlying controls.

Comment: I got around the  problem with the popupbox by creating my own popupbox and adding a timer event delay before popup that gets cancelled on every tab change.

Comment: The fmx code has provisions for automatically closing active 'picker' screens on tab changes in it but nothing for popups

Comment: Adding a foreground layout where catching gesture events allow you to stop cascading the onclick when it's not necessary.

Comment: I still want to respond to the onclick event. The problem seems to be that the click event precedes the gesture capture. Thus what needs to be done is to peek at the pending events and see that the click was actually part of the gesture.  Put a large button on a tab page and set the swipe gesture up to switch pages, when you swipe over the button you get the click event and then the gesture event. If you add a gesture manager over the button then the click event goes away.

Comment: I tried making the popupboxes just gesture manager aware, with long tap to 'click', which worked, but then the gesture manager for the button would never detect a swipe, because, I assume, that the button was too small..